# Spring Webflow AttributeMap doesn't apply default or check class when value is null

Tags: java, spring-webflow

Regarding Spring Webflow 2.4.1.RELEASE.

The [JavaDoc for AttributeMap](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/webflow/core/collection/AttributeMap.html) for **contains(String attributeName, Class requiredType)** states:

*"Does the attribute with the provided name exist in this map and is its value of the specified required type?"*

However, if the key is present but the value is null it considers this to be acceptable and does not throw IllegalArgumentException.

Similarly, the JavaDoc for **get(String attributeName, V defaultValue)** states

*"Get an attribute value, returning the default value if no value is found."*

However, if the key is present but the value is null, the default is not used.

This was previously raised as a [defect SWF-343 in 2007](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/web-flow/31959-why-no-null-value-allowed-in-attributemap)

This can be tested with eg

```
MutableAttributeMap<Object> flowScope = new LocalAttributeMap<Object>();

flowScope.put("key", null);

assertFalse(flowScope.contains("key", Boolean.class));

assertTrue((boolean) flowScope.get("key", Boolean.TRUE));

assertTrue(flowScope.getBoolean("key", Boolean.TRUE));
```

All of these end up going through this code in MapAccessor which is responsible for the treatment of null

```
public <T> T assertKeyValueInstanceOf(Object key, Object value, Class<T> requiredType) {
    Assert.notNull(requiredType, "The required type to assert is required");
    if(value != null && !requiredType.isInstance(value)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Map key \'" + key + "\' has value [" + value + "] that is not of expected type [" + requiredType + "], instead it is of type [" + value.getClass().getName() + "]");
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}
```

It seems that if the JavaDoc is correct then the code is wrong, or vice versa.

Should "null" pass the "requiredType" test for a specific type?

Should "null" be treated as a "value" when considering whether to apply a default?

If the code treated nulls the way the JavaDoc suggests, then I would be able to do something much cleaner:

```
if(getFlowScope().contains(key, Boolean.class)){
    return getFlowScope().getBoolean(key);
}

return false;
```

As it is, in order to safely access a flowScope attribute, allowing for key not present, null, and wrong type, I have to do something like this:

```
try {
        Boolean value = getFlowScope().getBoolean(key);
        return value == null ? false : value;

    }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        return false;
    }
```

Is there a cleaner alternative for a type-safe and null-safe retrieval of a flowscope attribute?